# Create a graph with a .name as source of data

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts

What Im trying to achieve is to create a graph/chart with a Name type as a source :

how to add data_name & "abs" as x axis

```
    'source
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:=data_name & "ord", RefersTo:= _
        "=OFFSET(data_calc!" & .Cells(9, c_write + 3).Address & ",0,0,data_calc!" & .Cells(6, c_write + 3).Address & "-1)"
    'X axis values
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:=data_name & "abs", RefersTo:= _
        "=OFFSET(data_calc!" & .Cells(9, c_write + 2).Address & ",0,0,data_calc!" & .Cells(6, c_write + 3).Address & "-1)"

    Dim graph As ChartObject
    'creating the graph
    Set graph = .ChartObjects.Add( _
        Left:=.Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 1).Left, _
        Width:=.Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 1).Width + .Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 2).Width + .Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 3).Width + .Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 4).Width + .Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 5).Width, _
        Top:=.Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 1).Top, _
        Height:=.Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 8, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 9, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 10, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 11, c_write + 1).Height _
        + .Cells(r_write + 12, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 13, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 14, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 15, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 16, c_write + 1).Height _
        + .Cells(r_write + 17, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 18, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 19, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 20, c_write + 1).Height + .Cells(r_write + 21, c_write + 1).Height)
    'adding the value, it doesnt work here
    graph.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Names(data_name & "ord")
    'here I don't know how to add data_name & "abs" as x axis
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook, frm, rngPlot As Range, cht As Chart
    Dim graph As ChartObject, s As Series
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    '...
    '...
    frm = "=OFFSET(data_calc!<addr>,0,0,data_calc!" & .Cells(6, c_write + 3).Address & "-1)"
    wb.Names.Add Name:=data_name & "ord", RefersTo:=Replace(frm, "<addr>", .Cells(9, c_write + 3).Address)
    wb.Names.Add Name:=data_name & "abs", RefersTo:=Replace(frm, "<addr>", .Cells(9, c_write + 2).Address)
       
    Set rngPlot = .Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 1).Resize(15, 5) 'plot covers this range
    
    Set graph = .ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rngPlot.Left, Width:=rngPlot.Width, _
                                 Top:=rngPlot.Top, Height:=rngPlot.Height)
    
    Set cht = graph.Chart
    RemoveData cht        'remove any "auto-added" series from the chart creation
    
    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
    s.Values = .Range(data_name & "ord")
    s.XValues = .Range(data_name & "abs")
    '...
    '...
End Sub

Sub RemoveData(cht As Chart)
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
End Sub
```

update : here is exactly what I wrote and I have an error 91 at line 13

```
Sub test_graph()
    Dim data_name As String
    data_name = "data1_1"
    Dim c_write1, r_write2, c_write2 As Integer
    c_write1 = 2
    c_write2 = 1
    r_write2 = 2
    
    With Worksheets("data_calc")
    Dim frm As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    frm = "=OFFSET(data_calc!<addr>,0,0,data_calc!" & .Cells(6, c_write + 3).Address & "-1)" 'error 91 here
    wb.Names.Add name:=data_name & "ord", RefersTo:=Replace(frm, "<addr>", .Cells(9, c_write + 3).Address)
    wb.Names.Add name:=data_name & "abs", RefersTo:=Replace(frm, "<addr>", .Cells(9, c_write + 2).Address)
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("data_analysis")
    Dim rngPlot As Range
    Dim s As Series
    Set rngPlot = .Cells(r_write2 + 7, c_write2 + 1).Resize(15, 5)
    Dim graph As ChartObject
    Set graph = .ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rngPlot.Left, Width:=rngPlot.Width, _
                                 Top:=rngPlot.Top, Height:=rngPlot.Height)
    Call RemoveData(graph.Chart)
    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
    s.Values = .Range(data_name & "ord")
    s.XValues = .Range(data_name & "abs")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank for the respond, so I just needed the
```
cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = .Range(data_name & "ord")
cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.XValues = .Range(data_name & "ord")
```
but now I have an error 1004.
also the `RemoveData cht` didn't worked so I put a `Call RemoveData(graph.Chart)` and this work. I still have the 1004 error though

Comment: `RemoveData cht` is exactly equivalent to `Call RemoveData(graph.Chart)` so I'm not sure why you needed the second version.  If you're getting an error it's helpful to tell us on which line you get the error, and what the *text* of the error is.

Comment: Hello, I back after some testing, here is what didn't work as you wrote it but with some changes I made it work, and also what didn't work. First, it seem like the "Dim" was creating errors, so I just took them away

Comment: ```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
frm = "=OFFSET(data_calc!<addr>,0,0,data_calc!" & .Cells(6, c_write + 3).Address & "-1)"
wb.Names.Add name:=data_name & "ord", RefersTo:=Replace(frm, "<addr>", .Cells(9, c_write + 3).Address)
wb.Names.Add name:=data_name & "abs", RefersTo:=Replace(frm, "<addr>", .Cells(9, c_write + 2).Address)
Set rngPlot = .Cells(r_write + 7, c_write + 1).Resize(15, 5)
Set graph = .ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rngPlot.Left, Width:=rngPlot.Width, _
                                 Top:=rngPlot.Top, Height:=rngPlot.Height)
Call RemoveData(graph.Chart)
```

Comment: it didn't show as intended on stack overflow. But this is where is stopped working, `cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = .Range(data_name & "ord")` gave me an error 1004

Comment: So I tested again and the dim seems to fine, idk why they didn't at first. But there is still the main problem. I tried with : `
    graph.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` and then `graph.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveWorkbook.Names(data_name & "ord").Value` but I still have the error 1004

Comment: Also - "it seem like the "Dim" was creating errors, so I just took them away" is not a good approach to writing robust code.  If you get errors with variable declarations, the thing to do is *fix the errors*...

Comment: here, I added the code as an update. For the "dim", it's very strange, as I had an error, then I tested again and it fine, and now I have an error 93, then I put it in comments, the put it back to normal state and it was fine, and now it gives me an error 91, but it is not the main problem, as the problem with ```graph.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = .Range(data_name & "ord")``` still give me the error 1004

Comment: Sorry I missed the nested `With` there (the outer one was not included in your post).  See update above.

Comment: Did the update to `Tester` fix the problem though?  If you're trying to post a huge amount of code and it won't let you, then you'll need to reduce it to the relevant parts.

Comment: it did not, I updated the code I tested and where I had an error

Comment: Try `s.Values = wb.Range(data_name & "ord")` if the name is scoped at the workbook level.  Same for the other name.

Comment: so I tried, it may work but the error is higher, at line 13 : `frm = "=OFFSET(data_calc!<addr>,0,0,data_calc!" & .Cells(6, c_write + 3).Address & "-1)"`, it give me an error 91